# SVG displays differently in Firefox then Chrome

Tags: html, firefox, svg

I encountered weird Firefox's and Edge's behaviour. It renders SVG images cutting parts of them. SVG works fine in Chrome but in Firefox and Microsoft Edge, it breaks.

In Firefox

[image: In Firefox]

In Chrome

[image: In Chrome]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <style>
      body {
        background: #000;
      }
      .continer {
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="continer">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
        <circle fill="rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4)" cx="10" cy="10" r="10"></circle>
        <circle
          stroke-dasharray="6.28 31.4"
          transform="rotate(-90) translate(-20)"
          stroke-width="10"
          fill="transparent"
          stroke="#ffffff"
          cx="10"
          cy="10"
          r="5"
        ></circle>
      </svg>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can't repro from FF70 on macOs in the given snippet (same result as Chrome's screenshot)

Comment: Don't set a stroke-width >= 2 x radius.

Comment: You mean change stroke-width to 9.9, If so I have changed it but that shows a small dot in the centre. Or something else?  @Robert Longson

Comment: You should use an arc path to draw an arc rather than trying to do it with a circle and stroke-dasharray.

Comment: How can I do that can you give me an example.

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#PathDataEllipticalArcCommands or use a tool such as Inkscape, that will likely create an arc with an arc path.

Answer (score 0):

Simple fix, just messed around with the code until I fixed it in Firefox
I don't specifically understand why this works but here's the fix:

```
stroke-width="9.9"
```

instead of:

```
stroke-width="10"
```

Comment: Yes, that works fine but there is a small dot in the centre!

Comment: Hmm, take a look at this: https://jsfiddle.net/gulraj/sgnm104j/

Comment: Yes, that works for stroke-dasharray="6.28 31.4" (20%) but for stroke-dasharray="15.7 31.4" (50%) there is a dot in the center.

Comment: I see it, it's the size of a pixel but it is there. Use the arc, it will fix the issue